# Flying Chennai to Auckland, do I need a transit visa in Melbourne?

Tags: indian-citizens, australia, transit-visas

I am from Chennai India, travelling to Auckland tonight with Student Visa, I have booked ticket in Malaysian Airlines,

Chennai - Kuala Lumpur, Kuala Lumpur - Melbourne, Melbourne to Auckland.

I will be staying in Melbourne for 3 hours, do I require a transit visa?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will - India is not on the [list of exemptions](https://www.border.gov.au/Lega/Lega/Form/Immi-FAQs/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-through-australia).

Because you are transiting in Australia, you will need the [Transit visa (subclass 771)](https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/771).